# NSPredicate : CoreData fetchRequest filtered by Array of dictionaries

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

Is it possible to create an NSPredicate using an array of dictionaries ?

I have a following structure :

```
[{ name: "foo", city:"Paris"},{name:"bar", city:"London"}]
```

An I want to filter my `NSFetchRequest` by these pairs. (supposing the properties have the same names in CoreData)

When passing an array I can use the keyword `IN`. But I don't get how make this work with an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to use `IN`, so you need to use a number of `OR`s.  In outline:

1. Iterate through all elements of the array.
2. For each element (`dictionary`), construct a predicate of the form:

   ```
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@ AND city == %@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"], [dictionary objectForKey:@"city"]];
   ```
3. Add each such predicate to a NSMutableArray (`array`) of predicates
4. Build a compound predicate from the array using:

   ```
   [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:array]
   ```

If performance is an issue, consider building the individual predicates with substitution variables rather than with format.