# Two properties comparison predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a core data object `Car` that has three properties `type`, `miles` and `year`

I'm fetching from the server an array of cars to import, as follow:
if this car is already in the db, then just fetch it from db and update its `miles` property
if not then create a new `Car` object and insert it to db.

two cars are equal if they have the same `type` AND `year`

i want to do the import with performance in mind, so I don't want to go over the cars array and fetch each one from db, I prefer to do one fetch to get all the cars that already in the db.

so finally the question:
how do I do such a fetch (what predicate should I use) that two properties are needed to be compared?

If only `type` was needed to compare cars then I could create a set of types from the cars array, and then fetch the cars with the same `type` from db with a simple predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type IN %@", arrayOfTypes"];
```

but here I need that not only the `type` will be equal but the combination of `type` and `year`

Comment: I think you will need to build a compound predicate.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29842519/3985749) to a very similar question.

Comment: it iterate through all elements of the array in that example

Comment: Yes, but only to build the predicate.  The fetch from the database occurs only once.